# PDE Sobolev Space, prove the equation holds weakly

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, elliptic-equations

> Prove for all $f\in L^2(0,1)$, there exists a unique $T(f) \in H^1(0,1)$, such that $$-T(f)''(x)+xT(f)'(x)+T(f)(x)=f(x) \quad \forall x\in(0,1).$$

I know we need to use Lax-Milgram theorem and find a bilinear form. I do not know to find the Bilinear form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show that there is a unique weak solution $T=T(f)$ in $H^1_0(0,1)$ in the sense that for every $U\in H^1_0(0,1)$,
$$ B[T,U]=\int_0^1 f(x)U(x) dx ,$$
where
$$B[T,U]=\int_0^1 T'(x)U'(x) + x T'(x) U(x) + T(x)U(x) \, dx.$$
We explicitly choose $$\|T\|_{H^1_0(0,1)} := \|T\|_{H^1(0,1)} = \sqrt{\|T\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 + \|T'\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2  }.$$ Clearly, $B$ is a bounded bilinear operator $|B[T,U]| \lesssim \|T\|_{H^1_0(0,1)} \|U\|_{H^1_0(0,1)}$. We only check coercivity:
\begin{align}
 \|T\|_{H^1_0(0,1)}^2 
&= \|T\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 + \|T'\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 
\\
&= B[T,T] - \int_0^1 xT'T\, dx
\\
& \le B[T,T] + \int_0^1 |T'T| \,dx
\\
& \le B[T,T] + \|T\|_{L^2(0,1)} \|T'\|_{L^2(0,1)}
\\
&\le B[T,T] + \frac12( \|T\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2+ \|T'\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2)
\\
&= B[T,T] + \frac12\|T\|^2_{H^1_0(0,1)}.
\end{align}
Thus
$$B[T,T] \ge \frac 12 \|T\|^2_{H^1_0(0,1)},$$
so $B$ is coercive. Hence, Lax-Milgram applies, giving the existence of a unique weak solution.

Comment: Thank  you for the help! The textbook used compact supported smooth function instead of U, I am guessing that compact supported function should be in $H^1_0$ as well?

Comment: @000000000 in fact $H^1_0$ is the closure of compactly supported smooth functions in the $H^1$ norm

Comment: In the above case, we have proved that the equation holds weakly in $H^1$. I am wondering what additional steps we need to use to approve it holds weakly in $L^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by "holds weakly in $L^2$"? @000000000

Comment: @000000000 Nothing extra needs to be done, because its legal to move the derivative from $T$ to $U$ in the above if $U\in C^2_c(0,1)$

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @000000000 you're welcome, would appreciate the +1 vote if you're satisfied :)